# Why no Daubechies wavelet from Continuous Wavelet Transform?

Tags: wavelet, cwt, dwt

thank you for considering this question. Do you know any reason why Daubechies wavelet can't be used for Continuous Wavelet Transfrom, but only for Discrete Wavelet Transform ? Matlab toolbox and Python packages don't allow for such transform, and I was wondering about theoritical rational here.
One surprising thing is use of Daubechies wavelet for CWT was implemented in Matlab 2012 but was removed on Matlab 2016, and I still can't find any reason for this.
Thank you